# How best to upgrade on netbook without lot of space?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade

I dont have a lot of space on my netbook. My 8GB drive is now almost full with about 250MB space. What is the best way to upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10? Will I have to download a lot of files? Can I use an USB drive for the upgrade?

Or is the best way to free up some space and upgrade as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Freeing up some space is anyway advisable.

But yes, you can also download the iso and make a live-usb. Then you can upgrade your ubuntu from the packages on the usb-drive (just start the installer, it will offer to upgrade)

For me it took around 1GB downloading to upgrade (I had quite some packages installed), so I think 250 MB will indeed not be enough for you.

Comment: I have a question on your answer. Do you mean 1 GB downloading while updrading by live USB?

(I'm asking this for I re-installed a fresh version, instead of upgrading, so I had to install my favorite apps again; but now I want to be sure if you've suggested a better way.)

Answer (score 2):

I you are having problems with a small storage space, you might want to look into Lubuntu. Lubuntu is a faster, more lightweight and energy saving variant of Ubuntu using LXDE, the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment. It is available from [their site](http://goo.gl/ylng) and is upgraded to version 10.10.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question will continually re-appear. Limited permanent storage: so perhaps install onto & run from a USB or flash card instead off the limited space on the PC hardware.

In Australia, most Linux distros install foreign languages, so I tediously remove them. Some install themes, wallpapers, lots of sample files (movies, sounds, pictures, fonts, etc). So - tediously remove these as well.

If you use a 'buntu running LXDE, this helps. When installing, do not allow Internet update whilst installing, because you have little control on the updates it will install.
Netbooks might run Atom (32bit) or I3 processors. Choose 32bit operating systems. If you have more than 3.5 GB of RAM memory on your motherboard, check that your op system is 32bit PAE. 64-bit apps, etc are usually more space demanding.

After the non-Internet install, use the inbuil upddater, or Synaptic to selectively choose what parts you will upgrade. On a small PC, you cannot do everything promised; only a few tasks.  So add your preferred apps rather than the ones that have been supplied.  Remove the unused apps; perhaps Transmision (torrent), Libreoffice and/or Abiword, etc.

With light usage, you can let 'buntu decide the size of your temporary and other folders, so just let it default install everything into the Root (/) directory.

Most netbooks need or allow wireless netweorks. So your might want to add wireless network apps: signal strength, security, etc. 'Sentinella' and hibernate apps might help as well, since these are rarely installed on most Linux distros, which are designed for desktop-type computers and servers.